# How to remove the h6 tag for the entry-category Class

Tags: php, html, blog-page

On my single blog pages at the very beginning, I have the html

```
<h6 class="entry-category is-xsmall">
    <a href="www.website.com" rel="category tag">category title</a></h6>
```

I want to remove the h6 tag from all blog pages. In this forum, I found a solution for removing the h3 at the comments:

```
    function my_comment_form_before() {
    ob_start();
}
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'my_comment_form_before' );

function my_comment_form_after() {
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = preg_replace(
        '/<h3 id="reply-title"(.*)>(.*)<\/h3>/',
        '<p id="reply-title"\1>\2</p>',
        $html
    );
    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'my_comment_form_after' );
```

I tried to change it to the h6 problem:

```
function my_comment_form_before() {
        ob_start();
    }
    add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'my_comment_form_before' );
    
    function my_comment_form_after() {
        $html = ob_get_clean();
        $html = preg_replace(
            '/<h6 class="entry-category is-xsmall"(.*)>(.*)<\/h6>/',
            '<p id="reply-title"\1>\2</p>',
            $html
        );
        echo $html;
    }
    add_action( 'comment_form_after', 'my_comment_form_after' );
```

But it is not removing the h6. How can I remove it the right way?

Comment: What's generating the h6? I can't see `<h6 class="entry-category is-xsmall">` in any of the core WordPress files, so I'd guess it's your theme? You probably want to make a child theme and override whichever template that is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need functions for this, just look in your theme's [template files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/): For single posts check `single.php` and for blog archive/categories check `archive.php`.

Change the `<h6>` in those php files to `<div>` or whatever you want. It would be wiser to override them with a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) so you don't lose your changes in a future update of the theme.